# determine the inverse of the following function: $f(x)= \frac{1}{3}x^2-6x+24$

Tags: functions

I do not know how to find the inverse of the equation. I know that we have to interchange the $x$ and $y,$ but I need somebody to show me the proper steps please.

Comment: Is it $$f(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^2-6x+24)$$?

Comment: but no brackets

Comment: Probably $\frac{1}{3}$ belongs to $x^2$.

Comment: That is correct

Answer (score 0):

You can write
$$3y=x^2-18x+72$$ (Multiplying by $3$)
and this is
$$3y=x^2-18x+81-9$$
$$3y+9=(x-9)^2$$ (completing the square)

Comment: so would the final answer be 3y+9=(x-9)^2?

Comment: i do not really understand what completeing the square means. Is there a way a final solution can be shown so I can learn what steps need to be taken?

Comment: Completing the square means adding $\big(\frac{b}{2a}\big)^2$ to both sides of an quadratic equation so the side with $ax^2+bx+c$ can be factored as a perfect square trinomial.

Comment: so how would we continue from where we left off from the solution above? I am a bit confused

Comment: Do you know how to solve quadratic equations? (For completing the square.)

Comment: "so would the final answer be 3y+9=(x-9)^2?" Well, no because that does not tell us what $y$ is.  The final answer will be $y = $ ... something to do with $x$....   $3y + 9 = (x-9)^2$ does not tell us what $y$ is.

Comment: Now you must take the square root: $$|x-9|=\sqrt{3y+9}$$

Comment: I need the proper steps needed to solve this question. Please help. I want to know what to do after 3y+9=(x-9)^2

Comment: You will get two equations for the inverse function: $$y=9+\sqrt{3x+9}$$ for $$x\geq 9$$ and $$y=9-\sqrt{3x+9}$$ for $$x<9$$

Comment: so there is 2 solutions?

Comment: why does the solution include 9- and 9+ ?

Comment: plus, would the inverse be a function? and how would be prove it

Comment: You have a parabola as the function and we get two inverse  functions, since the parabola isn't monoton.

Comment: Actually it is a badly worded question. If a function, $f$ is not one to one then two $x \ne w$ may map into the same $f(x) = f(w)$ and an "inverse" function does not exist.  Instead there are multiple functions that will work as inverses for some values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find (if possible; there might not be any) a function $g$ so that $f(g(x)) = x$

So if $g(x) = y$ then we want $f(y) = \frac 13y^2 -6y + 24 = x$

So if that is the case what is $y$ expressed in terms of $x$.

$\frac 13y^2 -6y + 24 = x$

$y^2 - 18y + 72 = 3x$

$y^2 - 18y = 3x - 72$

.....

$y = ....\text{ something to do with }x .....$

Whatever you get that will be $ g(x) = ....\text{ something to do with }x .....$.

Comment: You should also understand that, typically, a quadratic function **does not** have a true "inverse".  If $y= ax^2+ bx+ c$ (in your example, a= 1/3, b= -6, and c= 24) that is equivalent to $ax^ bx+ (c- y)$ and then $x= \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2- 4a(c- y)}{2a}$ (the "quadratic formula").  Choosing either the "+" or the "-" gives two different functions that, for some x, give an "inverse".

Comment: "You should also understand that, typically, a quadratic function does not have a true "inverse" which is why I said:  (if possible; there might not be any)

Answer (score 0):

$$y = \frac{1}{3}x^2-6x+24$$
Get rid of the $\frac{1}{3}$ by multiplying both sides by $3$.
$$3y = x^2-18x+72$$
Complete the square to factor the RHS easily. For $\color\red{a}x^2+\color\purple{b}x+c$, rewrite with $\big(\frac{\color\purple{b}}{\color\red{2a}}\big)^2$ so the side can be factored as a perfect square trinomial.

$$3y = x^2-18x+\biggr(\frac{18}{2}\biggr)^2-9$$
$$3y = (x-9)^2-9$$
$$3y+9 = (x-9)^2$$
$$x-9 = \pm\sqrt{3y+9}$$
$$x = \pm\sqrt{3y+9}+9$$
For $f^{-1}(x)$, any point $(x, y)$ on $f(x)$ will become $(y, x)$.

$$f^{-1}(x) \implies y = \pm\sqrt{3x+9}+9$$

Clearly, this isn’t a function because it has $\pm$ in it. But we can split it into two “inverses”.

Take a look at the original function. The vertex of the parabola is found by $-\frac{\color\purple{b}}{\color\red{2a}}$. Using that, you get $h = 9$ (try it and see). This is our minimum point. There are two parts, $x \geq 9$ and $x < 9$.

For $x \geq 9$, the inverse becomes 
$$y = 9+\sqrt{3x+9}$$

For $x < 9$, the inverse becomes 
$$y = 9-\sqrt{3x+9}$$